# Я правильно понимаю по логам, что ошибка тут в том, что база была выключена и java джоб не смог получить POST GET из базы

Tags: java, oracle, http, get, soap

И из-за этого выключились java джобы планировщика. Почему они выключились, а не продолжили работать?

```
2019-06-05 21:13:20.022  WARN 26392 --- [Timer-0] c.m.v.a.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner     : com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@3cdcca91 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
2019-06-05 21:13:20.028  WARN 26392 --- [Timer-0] c.m.v.a.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner     : com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@3cdcca91 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
    Managed Threads: 3
    Active Threads: 3
    Active Tasks: 
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@48ed9be5 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@6f994e19 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@12bf482b (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0)
    Pending Tasks: 
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@19f1bc21
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@453b9f24
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@61ad16d5
Pool thread stack traces:
    Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2,5,main]
        java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1805)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
    Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1,5,main]
        java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.forceKillAcquires(BasicResourcePool.java:853)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$1200(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1857)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
    Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0,5,main]
        java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1805)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)


2019-06-05 21:13:33.089  WARN 26392 --- [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2] c.m.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool    : com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@48ed9be5 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 

java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:275)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:264)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1452)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496)
    ... 11 common frames omitted

2019-06-05 21:13:33.090  WARN 26392 --- [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0] c.m.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool    : com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@12bf482b -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 

java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:275)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:264)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1452)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496)
    ... 11 common frames omitted

2019-06-05 21:13:33.092 ERROR 26392 --- [XNIO-2 task-23] ru.avk.scheduler.rest.JobControllerImpl  : 

ru.avk.scheduler.data.SchedulerApiException: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'DEFAULT': java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database! [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!]
```

Comment: Как по мне, так фраза `oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection` намекает на то, что в соединение было отказано, а не Не найден сервер

Comment: Почему соединение было отказано? В это время проводились работы по конфигурации БД .

Comment: Ну да, либо БД выключена, либо листенер перезагружался, либо перегрузка какая-то. Вам лучше знать скорее всего. Раз уж Вы хотите чтобы Вам помогли с джобами, то может больше расскажете про джобы: что у Вас за приложение, как джобы запускаются, как quartz настроен? Еще добавьте метку quartz так знающие люди быстрее обратят внимание.

Comment: Вы правильно поняли, листенер был доступен, а база была недоступна, т.е. не была зарегестрирована на листенере (перезагружалась наверное). А почему вы не связались с теми, кто проводил работы по конфигурации базы, а задали вопрос тут?